# Как передвинуть элемент выше границы?

Tags: java, android, разметка, toolbar

У меня есть фрагмент, который содержится во фрагмент контейнере  в `активити`. Но помимо контейнера, у `активити` сверху ещё стоит `тулбар`. Суть в том, что таким образом мне никак не передвинуть элементы выше контейнера, т.к. там стоит ещё `тулбар`, поэтому, когда я перехожу на фрагмент, в котором вызывается  метод `mainActivity.getSupportActionBar().hide();` , который прячет `тулбар`, у меня сверху остается пустое пространство, которое никак не заполнить. Вопрос заключается в том, каким способом возможно элемент передвинуть вверх (в данном случае- надпись Parepan)

**Как это выглядит в разметке AS**
[image: Как это выглядит в разметке в AS]

**Как это выглядит на реальном устройстве**
[image: Как это выглядит на реальном устройстве]

**Разметка активити**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    tools:layout="@layout/welcome_fragment"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:actionBarSize" />

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для `Activity` тему с `NoActionBar`, например `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. На превью у Вас именно эта тема и используется.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, конкретный код. android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar -этот почему-то не работает